# Append zero only if number is float

Tags: php, regex

I want to append zero at the end of the number but there are cases in which it is not required. For example,

```
150.1 //output should be 150.10
150.0 //output should be 150
150.00 //output should be 150
150.01 //output should be 150.01
150.10 //output should be 150.10
```

So if the number has a `.` and there is only one digit after the `.` and that digit is not `0` then i want to append `0` at the end of the number otherwise i want to display it as decimal number. I think there is a need for a regex in solving that issue but i am not good at it so any help is much appreciated.

Comment: number_format($input,2,'.','');

Comment: It won't remove .00 if there is.

Comment: @Dave `number_format(2.0,2,'.','')` will make it `2.00` but in this case i want to display it as `2` only

Comment: RE closure: please don't use this site to accommodate your laziness; at least some kind of attempt would have made this question fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this :

```
if (intval($numberToTest) != $numberToTest) {
   $numberFormated = number_format($numberToTest, 2);
}
```

Comment: This will almost work, but still retain the trailing 0 in values that have one significant figure after the decimal place e.g. `5.10`.

Comment: @MartyWallace That is what the OP wants, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, yes it is. Sorry about that :-P

Answer (score 1):

Format the number to have two trailing zeroes and then use a regex to remove the pattern - a `.` followed by one or more zeroes. A little function that does this:

```
function clean_num($num) {
        $num = number_format($num, 2, '.', '');
        return preg_replace('~\.0*$~', '', $num);
}
```

Test cases:

```
$numbers = array('150.1','150.0','150.00','150.01','150.10');
foreach ($numbers as $number) {
    echo clean_num($number).'<br>';
}
```

Output:

```
150.10
150
150
150.01
150.10
```